# PHP include " and ' character into a String

Tags: php, regex, string, character

I have a String in php variable. I want to add " and ' character before of the string variable and ' and " character after of my string variable. The following is my code but it fail to display what I wanted like "'String'"

```
$channel = """.$channel.""";
$channel = "\'".$channel."\'"
echo $channel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're escaping them incorrectly (*in the wrong order*).

What you want is this:

```
$channel = '"\'' . $channel . '\'"';
```

<sup>*Notice how we're escaping the `'` ? That's because we are using it to supply the string -> `'....'`. We need to escape it otherwise it'd "end" the string there. Causing syntax errors.*</sup>

[**Example/Demo**](https://www.tehplayground.com/R5pE8OhJTWn4aks4).

Answer (score 1):

```
    $channel = '"'.$channel.'"';
$channel = "\'".$channel."\'";
echo $channel;
```

i think the problem is you are foggeting to close your strings and you excapted them incorrectly

Comment: It comes with error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'

Comment: try it now @chanyoonghon